# Maven: Cannot resolve package doesn't exist when compile project

Tags: java, maven

A maven-base project has pom-parent.xml and pom.xml in project's root folder. In pom-parent.xml, I define:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In pom.xml, there is a corresponding dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

However, when running command `mvn install`, maven gave:

> error: package org.apache.commons.pool2.impl does not exist

which point to a line:`import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig;`

I also run command `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`,and commons-lang does occur:

[image]

Also, Intellij IDEA hint that it "Cannot resolve symbol StringUtils":

[image]

How to resolve this problem and compile the project successfully? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The class `org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig` is simply not contained in commons-lang. See here https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPoolConfig

Comment: You seem to need this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.4

Comment: As a side note, avoid using commons-lang that haven't been updated since 2011, use commons-lang3 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```